# How to remove one outlier in ggplot2 facet point_plot that squash the rest of the data

Tags: r, plot, statistics, ggplot2

I produced a faceted plot that I'm very satisfied with except for one issue. On a couple of the plots, one or two outliers completely ruin the graph. I could use y_lim function, but I'm using facet_grid(scales="free") so each plot has a unique limit. Here is my code and the graph it produced.

```
melted_df <- melt(df, id='ca_rmsd')
ggplot(melted_df,aes(ca_rmsd,value)) + geom_point() 
       + facet_grid(varible ~.,scales="free")
```

[image: produces]
<sub>(source: [willisjr at structbio.vanderbilt.edu](http://structbio.vanderbilt.edu/%7Ewillisjr/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-28%20at%205.49.02%20PM.jpg))</sub>

As you can see the top plot has a data point WAY outside the axis that smashes the rest.

Comment: Is this point a valid value? If not, you could (and perhaps should) your data prior to plotting (or at least after this plot which shows you an outlier)

Comment: No, I'm only interested in the funneling this may produce. This is a monte carlo search and there is bound to be crap values in my scoring function. But I need the overall shape of the graph. The problem is, I'm going to reuse this code again and again and can't be sure the ylim each time

Comment: Use some outlier detection procedure (see mvoutlier package perhaps) and remove these data.

Comment: While @mnel's suggestion is what you ought to do, a quick work around for your visuals is to set the `ylim`s explicitly (as opposed to letting `ggplot` pick them for you, which this is based on the data, including the outliers.)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- that is going to be difficult while working with melted data and faceting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility:

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n), y=rnorm(n),
                 label=sample(letters[1:4], size=n,
                   replace=TRUE))
df$y[1:50] <- 50  # Add some outliers

## Similar to your plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ label)

library(plyr)
df.quantiles <- ddply(df, "label", summarise,
                      q99=quantile(y, probs=0.99),
                      q90=quantile(y, probs=0.90))
df <- merge(df, df.quantiles, by="label", all.x=TRUE)

## More or less what you want?
ggplot(df[df$y < df$q99, ],
       aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ label)
```

This assumes there are only outliers above, but you could easily extend it to do the same below.

You could try something slightly more sophisticated, maybe

```
df[df$y < df$q99 | (df$q99 / df$q90) < some.ratio, ]
```

where you choose some.ratio so that you only throw out the largest 1% of Ys when they are deemed to be outliers, rather than all the time.

Hope that helps.